# Externalize XML construction from a stream of CSV in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization

I get a stream of values as CSV , based on some condition I need to generate a XML including only a set of values from the CSV. For e.g .

```
Input : a:value1, b:value2, c:value3, d:value4, e:value5.
if (condition1) 
XML O/P = <Request><ValueOfA>value1</ValueOfA><ValueOfE>value5</ValueOfE></Request>
else if (condition2)
XML O/P = <Request><ValueOfB>value2</ValueOfB><ValueOfD>value4</ValueOfD></Request>
```

I want to externalize the process in a way that given a template the output XML is generated accordingly. String manipulation is the easiest way of implementing this but I do not want to mess up the XML if some special characters appear in the input, etc. Please suggest.

Comment: suggest what? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could benefit from templating engine, something like [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an xsd and using [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) to create the Java binding classes that you can use to generate the XML.

Comment: Seriously create an XSD! It would be easier for him to just annotate the classes with JAXB annotations. Its pretty easy to figure out the mapping of the above xml.

Comment: Everyone likes to do things a certain way and I prefer to use an xsd. It's just a matter of personal preference since either way will work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend my own templating engine (JATL http://code.google.com/p/jatl/)  Although its geared to (X)HTML its also very good at generating XML.

I didn't bother solving the whole problem for you (that is double splitting on the input ("," and then ":").) but this is how you would use JATL.

```
    final String a = "stuff";
    HtmlWriter html = new HtmlWriter() {
        @Override
        protected void build() {
            //If condition1
            start("Request").start("ValueOfA").text(a).end().end();
        }
    };
    //Now write.
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    String results = html.write(writer).getBuffer().toString();
```

Which would generate

```
<Request><ValueOfA>stuff</ValueOfA></Request>
```

All the correct escaping is handled for you.